# How would I make my .jar file run on startup? Ubuntu/Pop!_OS

Tags: java, shell, jar

I have a program that I want to run every time I start up my computer. I am currently running Pop!_OS 20.10. After searching google I've learned that I need to create a shell script and place it in the `/etc/init.d` folder. After creating the file with the code below, and putting it inside the `/etc/init.d` folder path, nothing happened. After hunting more on google, I noticed that there is also a `/etc/rc.d` folder, but my system only has `/etc/rcn.d/` folders where n is a number from 0-6. I also cannot find a `/etc/rc.local` folder that other forums refer to.

```
#!/bin/sh
$ cd /home/user/Twenty2-Executable; java --module-path "/home/user/Downloads/javafx-sdk-15.0.1/lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.media -jar "/home/user/Twenty2-Executable/Twenty2-Java.jar"
```

I know my script runs fine because using the terminal to manually call the script makes my program run fine, the issues arise when I try to use it for startup. Basically nothing happens. Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Possibly some of the dependencies aren't loaded yet when you try to run that at startup

Comment: ohh ok... Do you think there's a way to delay it until everything loads?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using GNOME because you mention Pop!_OS.

For a user script these should be launched as session scripts by GNOME itself. Have a look under System > Preferences > Startup Applications. Make sure your script is executable with `chmod 777` and add it to startup applications.